# Extrelated-quip route type error installation for Experience Bundle unlocked package

Tags: scratch-org, unlocked-package, experience-cloud

We started getting an error while installing our unlocked package for Experiences last week: "Your site needs a route with route type extrelated-quip. Update your file and try again." We had a route with extrelated-quip already (the default one) and it is included in the package.  Is there some kind of new feature we need to put in the project-scratch-def.json?

Answer (score 2):

I had encountered the same error and it looks like it has been [acknowledged by Salesforce now](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000000xdQtQAI). I don't believe the direct fix has been made yet. However, what I did was go to a new sandbox and implement a new Community. Then, when I pulled the files down with:

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -u {your org alias} -m ExperienceBundle
```

I was able to locate the following Quip files:

- Routes: quipDocsRelatedList.json
- Views: quipDocsRelatedList.json

If you are adding those two files to an existing Experience Bundle, be sure you update the appPageId in both files to be the same as what are in your other json files. After that, my deployment worked.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, this helped me out 6 months later!